# Android sqlite tables to json file

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am new to json.  I am trying to get two Sqlite tables into a json text file. I am able to fetch each table and send to text file but my results are invalid if I try to read the string from the file.

Here is the code:

```
    File f = new File(Constants.DEFAULT_BACKUP_FILE_PATH);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f,true);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);

    String query1 = "SELECT " + COL_1  + "," + COL_2 + " FROM " + TABLE_1;
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(query1, null);
    cursor1.moveToFirst();

    JSONObject mObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray tab1Array = new JSONArray();


    int i = 0;
    while (!cursor1.isAfterLast()) {
        JSONObject rObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            rObject.put("id", cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(COL_1)));
            rObject.put("user", cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(COL_2)));

            cursor1.moveToNext();

            tab1Array.put(i, rObject);
            i++;

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    mObject.put("TABLE1", tab1Array);
    ps.append(mObject.toString());


    String query2 = "SELECT " + COL_1  + "," + COL_2 + " FROM " + TABLE_2;
    Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery(query2, null);
    cursor2.moveToFirst();

    JSONObject mObject2 = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray tab2Array = new JSONArray();


    int i2 = 0;
    while (!cursor2.isAfterLast()) {
        JSONObject rObject2 = new JSONObject();
        try {
            rObject2.put("id", cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(COL_1)));
            rObject2.put("name", cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(COL_2)));

            cursor2.moveToNext();

            tab2Array.put(i2, rObject2);
            i2++;

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    mObject2.put("TABLE2", tab1Array);
    ps.append(mObject2.toString());
```

My text file looks like this (note no comma between the two):

{"TABLE1":[{"id":"1", "user":"Larry"},{"id":"2", "user":"Mo"},{"id":"4", "user":"Curly"},{"id":"5", "user":"Shemp"}]}
{"TABLE2":[{"id":"1", "name":"Ticky"},{"id":"2", "name":"Tky"},{"id":"4", "name":"Tem"},{"id":"5", "name":"Bo"}]}

It should look like:
{
    "TABLE1": [{
        "id": "1",
        "user": "Larry"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "user": "Mo"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "user": "Curly"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "user": "Shemp"
    }],
    "TABLE2": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Ticky"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Tky"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Tem"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Bo"
    }]
}

I can parse TABLE1 but by:

```
        try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(backup);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("TABLE1");
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)     {

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String theId = jsonObject1.getString("_id");
```

but TABLE2 can't be found using the same code.  Any help would be great in building exporting the tables correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `ps.append(mObject.toString());` from the middle of the code, and change the last 2 lines to:

```
mObject.put("TABLE2", tab2Array);
ps.append(mObject.toString());
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much!!! and for the quick response.  I was closing the main object before adding the array.